# How to get the hour difference between 2 datetimestamp on derby db?

Tags: sql, database, derby

I have a sql question on derby database:

```
Select a.name, a.starttime, a.endtime
From a
```

How can I add to the above sql statement such that I can get the difference in hours between the start time and end time? (I only know that for mysql there is a DATEDIFF function, but I am not sure about what function should I use for derby db)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Derby there is a TIMESTAMPDIFF:

for instance:

```
select {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_FRAC_SECOND, startdate, enddate)} as diff
```