# Compare two time data types in sql

Tags: sql, time, derby

I want to get the min and max difference between two different time columns from my database but I'm not sure what function I am supposed to use to do this. I spent some time looking online and found something called timediff which I thought would work but apparently it doesn't exist. What function should I be using to carry out this statement? I made an attempt using timediff which doesn't work but should help anyone understand what I am trying to do.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, COUNT(ORDER_TYPE) AS TYPECOUNT,
MIN(TIMEDIFF(ORDER_ACCEPTED_TIME,ORDER_COMPLETION_TIME)) AS MINPREP,
MAX(TIMEDIFF(ORDER_ACCEPTED_TIME, ORDER_COMPLETION_TIME)) AS MAXPREP 
FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN '4/01/2015' AND '4/30/2015' AND ORDER_TYPE ='Breakfast' 
GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID
```

The above is the statement that I tried previously using the timediff method which doesn't work in my program. In addition, I am writing this code in java and am using jdbc connectivity and therefore am trying to write this statement into a string which gets passed as a statement later on

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11618722/1837329

Comment: What database are you using? Time and date types and functions differ a bit between various databases.

Comment: @jpw it's in java so using jdbc connectivity

Comment: @NickKaraolis But what database engine are you using? MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL or something else?

Comment: @jpw I'm using apache derby as the engine

Comment: Looks like you want the TIMESTAMPDIFF function. Looks at the [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefjdbc88908.html#rrefjdbc88908) and at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324522/how-to-get-the-hour-difference-between-2-datetimestamp-on-derby-db/2324557#2324557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `**SQL Server**`, Try [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Note: `DATEDIFF` won't give you a 'format'. It just returns an integer. So you'll need to cast/format appropriately.You can use the `108` format to `CAST` it to minutes/seconds.

Example:

```
DECLARE @dt1 datetime
DECLARE @dt2 datetime
SELECT @dt1 = '20090316 12:00:00.000', @dt2 = GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, @dt1, @dt2), 0), 114)
```

If you are using `**Oracle**` , there no similar function , BUT here's the way on how to do it:

> ENDDATE - STARTDATE will give you a number
>   that corresponds to the number of days between the two dates.
>
> If you want the result in hours, multiply by 24; if minutes, multiply
>   by 24*60 and so forth.
>
> You can also convert the result to an INTERVAL. There are two type of
>   intervals: NUMTODSINTERVAL(ENDDATE - STARTDATE, 'DAY') or
>   NUMTOYMINTERVAL(ENDDATE - STARTDATE, 'DAY')

[Source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic676470-338-1.aspx)

If you are using **`Derby`**,there is a **`TIMESTAMPDIFF`**:

> TIMESTAMPDIFF( interval, timestampExpression1, timestampExpression2 )

[Apache official documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/rrefjdbc88908.html)

Comment: The OP is not using MSSQL so this isn't very useful.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include Oracle. Thanks for the comment

Comment: But the OP isn't using Oracle either, the database used is Apache Derby.

Comment: Derby example included